How to get the first dropdown answer's value dynamically?
I have defined a custom question type, which name is cascadedropdown:
ComponentCollection.Instance.add({
  // A unique name; must use lowercase
  name: 'cascadedropdown', // A display name used in the Toolbox
  title: 'cascade dropdown', // A default title for questions created with this question type
  defaultQuestionTitle: 'choose the options',
  elementsJSON: [
    {
      type: 'dropdown',
      name: 'dropdown1',
      title: 'question1',
      choices: [
        {
          text:"apple",
          value:1,
        },
        {
          text:"orange",
          value:2,
        }
      ], 
    },
    {
      type: 'dropdown',
      name: 'dropdown2',
      title: 'question2',
      startWithNewLine: false,
      choices:getSecondLevelChoices(1)
    },
    {
      type: 'dropdown',
      name: 'dropdown3',
      title: 'question3',
      startWithNewLine: false,
      choices:[],
      visible: casecadeQuestionList.length > 2
    },
    {
      type: 'dropdown',
      name: 'dropdown4',
      title: '问题4',
      startWithNewLine: false,
      choices:[],
      visible: casecadeQuestionList.length > 3
    },
  ],
  inheritBaseProps: true
})

on the code above, there are at least two dropdowns in the casecadedropdown question, the second dropdown question's choices depend on the first dropdown answer. the method getSecondLevelChoices(1), the parameter 1 is the first dropdown answer's value.
How can I get the first dropdown answer's value dynamically?
The template is
<SurveyCreatorComponent :model="creator" />


You can solve this by defining the onValueChanged event as follows:
ComponentCollection.Instance.add({
  // A unique name; must use lowercase
  
  ... // the code above
  
  inheritBaseProps: true,
  
  onValueChanged(question,name){
    const question1 = question.contentPanel.getQuestionByName("question1");
    const question2 = question.contentPanel.getQuestionByName("question2");
    const question3 = question.contentPanel.getQuestionByName("question3");
    const question4 = question.contentPanel.getQuestionByName("question4");
    
    if(name === "question1"){
        question2.choices = getLevelChoices(levelTwoArray ,question1.value);
    }

    if(name === "question2" && question3.visible ){
        question3.choices = getLevelChoices(levelThreeArray ,question2.value);
    }

    if(name === "question3" && question4.visible ){
        question4.choices = getLevelChoices(levelFourArray ,question3.value);
    }
  }
})

Reference: expressions-and-triggers-in-composite-question-types
